# AngularJS Services API. Não carrega TITLE ao compartilhar link

Tags: php, rest, seo, angular

Boa tarde, preciso de uma ajuda para finalizar um projeto. Estou com um problema que ao compartilhar os links nas redes sociais, as tags title, description e etc não carregão com os valores retornados pela API (Utilizando AngularJS).

Acredito que o problema se da por conta que o Whats, Face etc, não carregam o Angular ou não espera a requisição, e então pega o código fonte, abaixo alguns prints para o melhor entendimento junto com o código:

Certo:
[Compartilhamento de forma correta no Face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imjZV.jpg)

Errado:
[Compartilhamento de forma errada no Face, como está hoje](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCZ3I.jpg)

Versão: AngularJS v1.6.1

Código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ecApp" ng-controller="ecCtlr">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
      <meta name="fragment" content="!">
      <title>{{produto.nome}}</title>
      <meta name="description" content="{{produto.texto_descricao}}" />
      <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="factory.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-init="buscaProduto(670706)" id="ecCtlr">
    </body>
</html>
```

Angular APP:

```
var api = 'http://localhost/api/';
var app = angular.module('ecApp', []);
var idLoja = 858;

app.controller('ecCtlr', function ($scope, $sce, ECProdutos) {

    $scope.buscaProduto = function(idProduto) {
        ECProdutos.buscaProduto(idLoja, idProduto).then(function (produto) {
            $scope.produto = produto;
            $scope.produtoPai = produto;
        });
    };
});
```

Factory:

```
angular.module("ecApp").factory("ECProdutos", function ($q, $http) {
    var urlClass = 'ec/produto/';
    return {
        buscaProduto: function (idLoja, idProduto) {
            var promessa = $q.defer();

            $http.get(api + '' + urlClass + 'buscaProduto/' + idLoja + '/' + idProduto).then(
                function (result) {
                    promessa.resolve(result.data);
                }
            );

            return promessa.promise;
        }
    };
});
```